# XPATHSelectElements returning null (no namespaces in XML file)

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, linq-to-xml

```
string xmlFile = GetCountriesFile();

XDocument xd = XDocument.Load(xmlFile);
XElement city = xd.XPathSelectElement("/WorldCities/City"); 

Console.Clear();
// Print the name of the first city
Console.WriteLine(city.Element("Name").Value);

// Get all the cities in the document
// Works in http://xpath.online-toolz.com/tools/xpath-editor.php
// but returns null in .NET
var cities = xd.XPathSelectElements("/WorldCities/City"); 
// cities is set to nulll

Console.ReadKey();
```

The XML file I am using contains no namespaces:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> <!-- XML declaration, there can only be one XML declaration in an XML document -->

<WorldCities> <!-- Root node, there can only be one root node in an XML document -->

  <City> <!-- Parent node -->
    <Name>Vancouver</Name> <!-- Child node -->
    <Country>Canada</Country>         <!-- Sibling node of location -->
    <Continent>North America</Continent> <!-- Sibling node of location -->
  </City>

  <City>
    <Name>Buenos Aires</Name>
    <Country>Argentina</Country>
    <Continent>South America</Continent>
  </City>

  <City>
    <Name>Berlin</Name>
    <Country>Germany</Country>
    <Continent>Europe</Continent>
  </City>

  <City>
    <Name>Nairobi</Name>
    <Country>Kenya</Country>
    <Continent>Africa</Continent>
  </City>

  <City>
    <Name>Tokyo</Name>
    <Country>Japan</Country>
    <Continent>Asia</Continent>
  </City>

  <City>
    <Name>Sydney</Name>
    <Country>Australia</Country>
    <Continent>Australia</Continent>
  </City>


</WorldCities>
```

The XPATH tester at http://xpath.online-toolz.com/tools/xpath-editor.php returned all of the City elements when I used the XPATH path "/WorldCities/City" against the same XML. Why then is the XPATHSelectElements method returning null? There are no namespaces in the XML file to cause problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That method never returns null, it instead returns an `IEnumerable<XElement>` you have to consume in your code to access the elements in the collection, if there are any selected. But you won't get a null from that method.

Comment: When I types "cities" in the immediate window, it returned the null result below that's why I said the method returns null:

"cities
{System.Xml.XPath.XPathEvaluator.EvaluateIterator<System.Xml.Linq.XElement>}
    result: null"

Anyway, I added the code below after cities, and I was able to print the names of the cities. Thank you both for your help.

foreach (XElement c in cities)
{
  Console.WriteLine(c.Element("Name").Value);
}

Answer (score 0):

Your XPath is correct and your code works fine with xml you provided - it returns first city element for first query and collection of 6 cities for second query:

[image]

My first thought was that you are loading some other file. But thus your first query returns first city element, then your second query should return at least one city. Looks like you are not using same xpath for second query. Make sure your real code is *exactly* same as code you provided.

Comment: I checked the xd variable and it contains the correct XML text which means it's getting the text from the correct XML file. I am able to query the cities using DataSet and LINQ, only the XPATHSelectElements method is returning null.

Comment: @user3147936 with code and data you provided, it does not return null